# How to check if g++ supports c++14/17 in SCons?

Tags: c++11, compilation, g++, c++14, scons

I'm using scons as my build system.

Some of my code is for cpp14 and cpp17. They're in folders like "newcpp". I wish my SConstruct/Sconscript could check if my g++ supports these flags, pseudo code like below:

```
import os,sys
env = Environment(ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']})
if [CXX_SUPPORTS('-std=c++14')]
    env.SConscript(dirs=['newcpp'])
```

I know that automake/configure supports this kind of check. How to do it in scons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you want to use Configure Contexts.
See this section of the Users Guide
https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/ch23.html

And this section of the manpage:
https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#configure_contexts

So likely you'll want something like this:

```
env = Environment(CFLAGS='-std=c++14')
conf = Configure(env)
if conf.CheckCXX():
   print("Yes CXX14")
   env.SConscript(dirs=['newcpp'])
env = conf.Finish()
```